# Update if Transaction Condition Fails in DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, rust, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

Using Rust with AWS SDK. I'm trying to update the dynamo table with one thing if the condition_check fails and update it with another thing if the condition_check succeeds. Trying to do this atomically with one single request. I know that an entire transaction fails if one condition fails so I was wondering if this is even possible?

Comment: This is not for the same item presumably. You can't target the same item with multiple operations within the same transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Your semantics are not possible on a single request. I would try the request which is most likely to succeed first, then if it fails retry with the other request.

If the likelihood of them succeeding is 50/50 then sometimes is best to read the item first, as reading the item is more cost effective than 2 writes.